# Crystal Report print button causes C# webform to POSTBACK rendering other button unable to fire again

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I had an issue with Crystal Report in C# Webform. I had create a webpage & it was able to load the report via Crystal Report Viewer successfully but the problem is that once the user clicked on the Print button of the Crystal Report Viewer, it will cause the page to change into POSTBACk thus rendering my other buttons on the webpage unable to fire's the programmed events again. So does anyone had a solution to this problem of mine, please guide me? Your assistance is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance. Below is my code

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
namespace Report1
{
   protected void Page_Load(..)
   {
      //Previous code
      //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      //{  LoadReport();  }
      //else
      //{  LoadReport();  }

      //Recommended code
      LoadReport();
   }

   protected void Button1_Click()
   {
      Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
   }

   protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init()
   {}

   private void LoadReport()
   {
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectionInfo.ServerName = @"server";
        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "tbl1";
        connectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
        connectionInfo.Password = "sa";
        connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
        connectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;

        string strParam = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Param"]);
        label1.Text = strParam;

        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

        Report1 crystalReport1;
        crystalReport1 = new Report1();

        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        SetDBLogonForReport(connectionInfo, cryRpt);

        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("Param", strParam);
        CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{Param}";
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport1;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
   }

    private void SetDBLogonForReport(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ReportDocument reportDocument)
    {
        Tables tables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            tableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

code behind

```
<%@Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs"       Inherits="Project.Report" %>

 <td class="style5">
    <asp:Button ID="MainButton" runat="server" onclick="MainButton_Click" 
       Text="Back To MainPage" Width="174px" CausesValidation="False" />
          </td>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
       <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True"
                AutoDataBind="True" Height="1269px" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="881px" 
                oninit="CrystalReportViewer1_Init" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" 
                GroupTreeStyle-ShowLines="False" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" 
                ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelView="None" 
                EnableParameterPrompt="False" SeparatePages="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" 
                HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" />
            <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
                <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
                </Report>
            </CR:CrystalReportSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is right here:

```
protected void Page_Load(..)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {  LoadReport;  }
  else
  {  LoadReport;  }
}
```

You call the LoadReport function whether it is postback or not.

Comment: So what u mean is like what i had edited above the code. I had tried but the result is still the same. Is there a workaround for this apart from this solution??

Comment: I think you want protected void Page_Load(..)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {  LoadReport;  }}

Comment: And are you using the Report Viewers print button?

Comment: Yeah! I'm using the ReportViewer print button to do the printing.. And I had tried your advice steps, results still the same

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. So I will only need to call the LoadReport function only during Not Postback will do. I did try before that method, but that will render my Report print button to unable to print the report instead??

Hi Campanolo_1,

Still can't do it using asp:button Response.Redirect(). So I decided to use javascript: onclick button to do the same redirect [onclick=window.location('MainPage.aspx')].. Ironically it works quite well with the CrystalReportViewer postback or !postback.